# ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn.range_to_string gone from Rails 4.1 -> 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-postgresql

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn.range_to_string gone from Rails 4.1 -> 4.2

My searches on the web were so fruitfull that I finished hardcoding the 4.1 version into our code, and I do not like that.

Anything I missed, hopefully.

Thanx

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the rails github page? There must be a reason for the removal if this method. I cannot find anything about this sadly, except the actual code from 4.1

Comment: @Iceman thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It looks like that logic moved to `type_cast_for_database` in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/02579b56bbe0de17ce8657f453ad4f02acc4ab84#diff-5223602a7f4885ee187b37792044b59d)